# Can somebody run me through a clean install of 13.10?

Tags: system-installation

I'm running 12.04 right now.  I didn't keep Windows on my computer.  And I want to put it on an HP Pavilion g6 laptop.   Somebody guided me through it last time.  I remember having to update repositories and a couple other things after the install, but I can't remember, and I can't find a site that explains it thoroughly.

Comment: Do you want to update from 12.04  to 13.10 (` having to update repositories `) or do you want a clean install (as your title suggest)?

Comment: Clean install.  I found this:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CleanUpgrade  but I'm still a little confused.

Comment: I've had a lot of error messages lately, so I just want to start fresh(do a clean install).

Comment: I've had a lot of error messages lately, so I just want to start fresh(do a clean install).  Should I run a disk-wiping utility as suggested here:  http://michaelmgriffin.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Do-a-Clean-Install @OrangeTux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have selected a tutorial that has a lot of screenshots (15) and not too much text (because you don't need a verbose tutorial if there are plenty of screenshots). The tutorial is called [Installing Ubuntu 13.10](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Installing-Ubuntu-13-10-396266.shtml) by Marius Nestor.

In my opinion the best advice for installing Ubuntu is to make sure you have a working internet connection. If necessary run the live Ubuntu DVD/USB and start the Ubuntu installer from it. You can open Firefox from the live DVD/USB and check that you have a working internet connection before you start the Ubuntu installer. In the Ubuntu installer there are options to install many different packages that you would normally need all together with a single click. This will save you a lot of time compared to installing all of the same packages one at a time using the Ubuntu Software Center. You can also download all the updates while you are still in the Ubuntu installer, so that Ubuntu will be completely up to date before you restart and run it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you want to update your current 12.04 to 13.10.

Ubuntu have a full document available on doing updates like this  [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades).

If you want to just run a terminal command if memory serves it's:

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

If, however, you are trying to install the updates version on a new machine simply download the ISO from  [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop), burn it to a disk and install.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.  I think I found what I was looking for here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CleanUpgrade

Comment: That should work just fine to. Hope it all goes well for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a fresh install. Maybe this helps: [Move your Ubuntu system to another computer in 3 simple steps](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/)